# Powershell Limit-EventLog OverflowAction not working

Tags: powershell, event-log

Using powershell 4 the code:

```
Limit-EventLog -LogName Application -MaximumSize 64KB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
```

fails to produce the desired effect. The LogSize is changed, however the OverFlow action is not changed. Specifying a different value for the OverflowAction also fails to change anything, and the value OverwriteOlder throws an error claiming that the maximum size being passed in needs to be a multiple of 64kb, which it already is.

Anyone have any ideas how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: (1): Technet says: 'To use Limit-EventLog on Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, open Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option.' Are you doing this? (2): Have you tried issuing the command with just the `-overflowaction` parameter?

Comment: How are you checking if the OverFlow item changes? I just tried it and worked ok for me. Had to open and close the Properties tab to see the changes.

Comment: Your synax works fine for me, even with a log size of 2048KB

Comment: This is strange- I have tried on multiple computers and have gotten the same result. I am checking by looking at the properties tab, and yes I do close it before rechecking. I was assuming since I was getting the same results on 5 VMs that it would be reproducible for others. Strange, maybe not...

Comment: I have tried again today with the same result. The code in my question fails to change the overflow action to Overwrite events as needed, remaining instead on Archive the Log When Full. The size is changed if the size is passed in, and if it is not the overflowaction still does not change.

Comment: Can you check the value of this registry key prior to trying the update via powershell and after? You mention 5 computers doing this, is there possibly a group policy setting this for you?

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application

Answer (score 1):

Not a pure powershell solution, but you can to do it with [wevtutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848(v=ws.10).aspx) built-in command :

your `overflowaction` parameter is corresponding to the `retention` parameter in wevtutil (true = keep old events -> new events will be rejected)

set the config :
`wevtutil.exe sl application /Rt:false`

Comment: Setting it to false throws an error "Channel property Retention contains invalid value. The value has invalid type, is outside of valid range, can't be updated or is not supported by this type of channel"

Comment: It may be something unique to my situation then. Also this is on windows8/windows server 2012. I was running it in an elevated powershell

Comment: Try within cmd.exe  then

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is only occurring when the existing value is archive (it works fine when changing from "Don't Overwrite").

The reason seems to be that when it is set to archive a key called "AutoBackupLogFile" is created and the existing key "Retention" is set to a max value, but the cmdlet is failing to change those values appropriately so it is a bug with the cmdlet and unfortunately if you are trying to change the value from Archive to something else, the cmdlet will not work for that purpose. The best answer here is to just directly adjust the appropriate registry keys.

Also note that the cmdlet is incorrect about the minimum allowable size of the event log. The minimum size is actually 1mb, so 64kb is not a valid value.

Here is a simple script that will change all 3 main logs to the smallest size and adjust to overwrite as needed (if you only want to do application just remove security and system from the array):

`@('Application','Security','System') | % {
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\$_" -Name MaxSize -Type DWORD -Value 0x00100000 -Force
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\$_" -Name AutoBackupLogFiles -Type DWORD -Value 0 -Force
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\$_" -Name Retention -Type DWORD -Value 0 -Force
}`

Note, you'll want to double check the formatting if you copy that and ensure each "set-itemproperty" is on the same line.

Comment: A registry key value is valid I guess. I was hoping to avoid touching it directly. When I get back to the computers I will try this.